# Why is $\int_{A}{\frac{y^2}{r_0-y}dA}=\int_{A}{-y dA}+r_0\int_{A}{\frac{y}{r_0-y}dA}$?

Tags: integration

My textbook on Advanced Mechanics of Solids makes the following substition

$$\int_{A}{\frac{y^2}{r_0-y}dA}=\int_{A}{-y dA}+r_0\int_{A}{\frac{y}{r_0-y}dA}$$

The context is curved beams, but I don't know if that is relevant.

How is this substitution valid? $y$ is distance along the y-axis, as usual.  $dA$ is an infinitesimal area on the surface.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses linearity of the integral and the fact that:

$-y+\frac{r_{0}y}{r_{0}-y}=\frac{-y(r_{0}-y)+r_{0}y}{r_{0}-y}=\frac{y^{2}}{r_{0}-y}$

Comment: Haha thanks. Should have thought that through.

Comment: Your welcome. Glad to help.